# reverse() is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I wrote within javascript a function to calculate the stock of our ticket system. As input, i  get the following input:

```
[{key:"10-09-2017", value:{countCreatedTickets: 98, countOpenTickets: 13, countSolvedTickets: 61}},
 {key:"12-09-2017", value:{countCreatedTickets:51,  countOpenTickets: 14, countSolvedTickets: 33}}
]
```

The function as i used is:

```
function funnelCalulation(ds){
    var stock = 0, stockCalulations = []
    console.info('-------  funnelCalulation -------')
    console.info(ds)
    ds = ds.reverse()

    for(var i = 0; i < ds.length; i++ ){
        if (i == 0){
            stock = ( ds[i].value.countCreatedTickets + ds[i].value.countOpenTickets ) - ds[i].value.countSolvedTickets
            stockCalulations.push({datum: ds[i].key, createdTickets: ds[i].value.countCreatedTickets, opentTickets: ds[i].value.countOpenTickets, ticketStock: stock })

        }
        if (i > 0){
            stock = ( ds[i].value.countCreatedTickets + ds[i].value.countOpenTickets + stock ) - ds[i].value.countSolvedTickets
            stockCalulations.push({datum:ds[i].key, createdTickets: ds[i].value.countCreatedTickets, opentTickets: ds[i].value.countOpenTickets, ticketStock: stock })
        }
    }

    return stockCalulations[ds.length-1]
}
```

I called the function as followed:

```
var stockValues = funnelCalulation(values)
            console.info('  ---- > stockValues  <--------')
            console.info(stockValues)
```

console.info(ds) returns the following output:
[image]

and if i type typeof ds it returns that is a object. The result is the function works correct but when returning the value gives the following error back:

```
ticketsGraphs.js:49 Uncaught TypeError: ds.reverse is not a function
    at funnelCalulation (ticketsGraphs.js:49)
    at Object.success (createWidgets.js:121)
    at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
```

I put the complete code in the jsfilde below:

https://jsfiddle.net/Erik_Hoeven/Lahuc4oe/

Comment: are you sure that `ds` is an array? What does the `console.log(ds)` input?

Comment: What is `typeof ds`? If `ds` is an array, this error can't happen.

Comment: [Not reproduceable](https://jsfiddle.net/zfpzydgv/). Your input is a JSON string instead of an array?

Comment: I put the answers of your questions in the orginal post. It is indeed no array but an object. Even when i set the var explicit to an array.

Comment: Could you add the code relating to the AJAX call?Which calls the funnelCalulation function?

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass .reverse() an array.

```
 function funnelCalulation(ds){
        var stock = 0, stockCalulations = []
        console.info('-------  funnelCalulation -------')
        console.info(ds)
        ds = ds.toString().split('').reverse().join('')

        for(var i = 0; i < ds.length; i++ ){
            if (i == 0){
                stock = ( ds[i].value.countCreatedTickets + ds[i].value.countOpenTickets ) - ds[i].value.countSolvedTickets
                stockCalulations.push({datum: ds[i].key, createdTickets: ds[i].value.countCreatedTickets, opentTickets: ds[i].value.countOpenTickets, ticketStock: stock })

            }
            if (i > 0){
                stock = ( ds[i].value.countCreatedTickets + ds[i].value.countOpenTickets + stock ) - ds[i].value.countSolvedTickets
                stockCalulations.push({datum:ds[i].key, createdTickets: ds[i].value.countCreatedTickets, opentTickets: ds[i].value.countOpenTickets, ticketStock: stock })
            }
        }

        return stockCalulations[ds.length-1]
    }
```