# Where is the problem ? 'Add Two Numbers , leetcode problem'

Tags: javascript

This is a problem in leetcode, and that is my solution
the program run with me in vs code but in leetcode he types error: *l1.reverse is not a function*

https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/

> You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative
> integers. The digits are stored in reverse order, and each of their
> nodes contains a single digit. Add the two numbers and return the sum
> as a linked list.
>
> You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except
> the number 0 itself.

```js
// Input: l1 = [2,4,3], l2 = [5,6,4]
// Output: [7,0,8]
// Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807.

let l1 = [2, 4, 3],
  l2 = [5, 6, 4];
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {
  l1 = l1.reverse().join("");
  l2 = l2.reverse().join("");
  let l3 = parseInt(l1) + parseInt(l2);
  return l3
    .toString()
    .split("")
    .reverse()
    .map((ele) => {
      return Number(ele);
    });
};
console.log(addTwoNumbers(l1, l2));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reverse() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215260/reverse-is-not-a-function)

Comment: The leetcode problem says the input is linked lists. Your code expects arrays.

Comment: hint: l3 is not the same type as l1, and l2. that is why you can't call reverse() on it.

Comment: @nycynik The error is happening on `l1.reverse`. It doesn't happen in this snippet because `l1` is an array, but leetcode is calling it differently.